Solving a Set Theory Problem Involving Intersections, Unions, and Complements
I'm struggling with a particular set theory question and would greatly appreciate some guidance. The problem is as follows:
Let $A=\{1,2,5,6,7\}$, $B=\{0,4,6,7,9\}$, and $C=\{0,1,2,6,7,9\}$ be subsets of $S=\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. I need to determine which subsets $X$ of $S$ satisfy the equation
$$ (A \cap X) \cup (B \cap X^c) = C. $$
Here, $X^c$ denotes the complement of $X$ within the universal set $S$.
I understand that $A \cap X$ refers to elements common to both $A$ and $X$, and $B \cap X^c$ includes elements in $B$ but not in $X$, with their union needing to equal $C$. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to approach finding all possible subsets $X$ that meet this criterion.
Could someone please explain a step-by-step method to solve this problem? If there are any specific theorems or concepts that could simplify the process, I'd love to learn about those as well.
I'm familiar with basic set theory operations like unions, intersections, and complements but applying them in this context has been challenging for me.

Is 0 in X or not?

What do you mean by o?

Sorry. The digit $0$

It's not in X..

That is correct. Now you have solve already $10%$ of your problem and can go for the remaining $90%$

You can consider some cases. (I use "$-$" to denote set difference; i.e., $A - B = A \cap B^c$.)

If $s \in (A - B) \cap C$, then we must have that $s \in X$.
If $s \in (B - A) \cap C$, then we must have that $s \in S - X$.
If $s \in (A - B) \cap (S - C)$, then we must have $s \in S - X$.
If $s \in (B - A) \cap (S - C)$, then we must have $s \in X$.
If $s \in A \cap B \cap C$ or $s \in (S - A) \cap (S - B) \cap (S - C)$, then it doesn't matter whether $s \in X$ or not.

Note that there is no solution for $X$ if there exists $s \in A \cap B \cap (S - C)$, or if there exists $s \in (S - A) \cap (S - B) \cap C$.
Let's iterate through the elements of $S$ and categorize them into the cases above.

$0$ is case 2.
$1$ is case 1.
$2$ is case 1.
$3$ is case 5.
$4$ is case 4.
$5$ is case 3.
$6$ is case 5.
$7$ is case 5.
$8$ is case 5.
$9$ is case 2.

From this, we see that the elements $1, 2, 4$ must be included in $X$, while the elements $0, 5, 9$ must be included in $S - X$. The remaining elements $3, 6, 7, 8$ are "free" and can belong to either $X$ or $S - X$. There are $16$ possibilities, depending on whether you include each of the "free" elements in $X$ or not.
